# Linked Videos to Yourself or Others

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are linked youtube videos on topic. For instance, if I post a video of myself swimming, and ask a narrow enough topic for how I should improve, that seems to be on topic.

Where I feel there is a gray line is that that video could disappear at any point (well, the internet doesn't forget, but still). If it ends up being deleted, a video of yourself will likely not resurface.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe should be fine.

However, I would (in response to the video disappearing, or link dying) explain what is being done and what is seeking improvement (by means of detailed explanation, or screenshots -- as you can add images to your posts -- of your form at half second intervals (or something plausible) to demonstrate what is being done).

Comment: I like the idea of images.